# Improper integral evaluates to $-\pi^2/12$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x} \mathrm{d}x=-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Please, help give me proper hints to solve.

I was not even able to equate the first two.

Comment: Once you get to the second integral, expand the integrand in a power series, integrate term-by-term, and refer to a famous summation.

Comment: Tried but $\int_{-1}^{0}ln(x+1)/x+2$ . that does not solve problem!

Comment: I think the first equality follows via integrating by parts, where $u = \ln(x)$ and $dv = \frac{dx}{1+x}$, and we let $\int u dv = uv - \int v du$.

Comment: The change of variable $y=1+x$ is indeed useless...sorry.

Comment: @julien you removed your comment and now comment has became useless.

Comment: It's not completely useless. For silly people like me, it says: don't try the change of variable $y=1+x$ in the first integral, like in the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of comments above I myself Post a Answer to my Question!!

using integration by parts.
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x+1}dx=\left[\ln x\ln(1+x)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx$$

And now using $$\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4.....$$
 we get $$-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} dx=-\int_0^1(1-x/2+x^3/3-x^3/4)dx$$
$$-\int_0^1(1-x/2+x^3/3-x^3/4)dx=-[1-1/2^2+1/3^3-1/4^2........]$$
and finally we know. $$-[1-1/2^2+1/3^3-1/4^2........]=-\pi^2/12$$
And so the answer

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: I do not understand why you rejected my review! it improved the answer unless you think the change of variables is wrong

Comment: It created a term with limit -1 to -2 which will increase my problems to change the limits.

Comment: you are right, I missed that, sorry

Comment: I'm glad my comment was helpful.